# Need to create a SQL statement in MS Access (2010) to count multiple records in a range

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two tables in MS access.  Need to create a table that lookups the ranges in table1 and counts the records in table2, within that range.

Table1

```
FROM        TO
00100000    00799999
00800000    00899999
00900000    01599999
01600000    01899999
```

Table2

```
Acct
00103614
00103615
00103624
00103626
00104001
00104002
00104003
00104004
00104302
00104400
00104401
00104404
00104406
00104407
01622345
01622347
01622353
01622357
01622359
01622362
01622365
01622366
01622368
```

Desired output:

```
FROM        TO          Count
00100000    00799999    50
00800000    00899999    10
00900000    01599999     0
01600000    01899999    42
```

Thanks
Frank

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like this:

```
select count(*) as count, table1.tfrom, table1.to
from table2, table1
where table2.acct between table1.tfrom and table1.to
group by table1.tfrom, table1.to;
```

please avoid "SQL" words like from and to in table/column names

Comment: I tried this and i get a syntax error (comma) in query expression 't1.acct between t1.from, t1.to'

Comment: fixed: added semicolon at the end and `and` in `between` clause

Answer (score 0):

Use *correlated* subquery :

```
select *, (select count(*) 
           from table2 t2 
           where t2.acct >= t1.from and 
                 t2.acct <= t1.to
          ) as Count
from table1 t1;
```